# Accessing files with spaces in filename from Java

Tags: java, file, operating-system

I want to access files in a directory which have spaces in filename from a java program but it doesnot access file.

Scenario is i have names of file in a file . iread file names from that file and not able to open files with spaces in java .

We are using File.exist function to check if file exist but it return false.

i have tried several kind of formats to represent spaces llike "ab\ c"for file name ab c and ab%20c for same file.

but nothing is helping.

Comment: Show us some code and examples.  Java *per se* handles spaces in filenames just fine with no escaping or anything.

Comment: You may be trying to access a file the user running the jvm don't have access to. It was my case.

Answer (score 13):

decode the path, just like this

```
String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 11):

This works fine for me. I do not escape them at all.

```
System.out.println(new File("/tmp/test 1/").exists());
```

Ensure you are useing the correct file separator for your operating system.

```
System.getProperty("file.separator")
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the similar problem while trying to read a resource location from **Servlet** on a **Windows** OS. The following line worked for me.

```
String path = config.getServletContext().getResource("/app").toString();
path = URLDecoder.decode(path,"UTF-8");
path = path.replaceAll("file:/", "");
path = path.replaceAll("\\u0020", "\\ ");
File verLocation = new File(path);
```

After all of the above line the verLocation.exists() is returning true else was also false.

Answer (score 3):

Try [converting it to a URL](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-to-convert-a-file-to-a-url)

```
URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I've never had problems with spaces in filenames while reading through Java. Just make sure you escape the path separator properly. I hope the filenames, if you're about to print out using Java, resolve to existing files with proper access permissions.

Answer (score 1):

if u are taking input as a file path the try using `sc.nextline()` to read white spaces