# How to read/open files with space in name

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream, mplayer

I'm trying to develop a server for `mplayer` using Java but I can't open files that have spaces in name (e.g. "File with space.mp3").

I'm following this tutorial [here](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/30/jmplayer/). The problem is, every time I try to open a file with spaces in name the `getInputStream()` read only the string before the space, generating a "file not found" error.

The path are correct in command, I tried even different formats (e.g. "File\ with\ space.mp3", "$PATH/File with space.mp3", etc), but nothing works.

What can I do to get data properly from `getInputStream`? How to avoid `getInputStream` to block when it founds a space in the String?

Ps. I use a linux system and the codes are the same as the link above (ctrl+c , ctrl+v).

thanks for the help.

Comment: It might help to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Have you tried either escaping the space or using unicode characters? (Not sure if that will work - just thinking out loud)

Comment: You can try this: http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/opening-file-with-a-space-in-its-filename-515638.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358850/accessing-files-with-spaces-in-filename-from-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the use of `Runtime#exec`.  It thinks that the space in the file is another parameter.

```
Process mplayerProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/to/mplayer -slave -quiet -idle file/to/play.avi");
```

Instead, you should use `ProcessBuilder` which allows you to specify each parameter as a separate `String` eliminating the need to mess about with quotes.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/path/to/mplayer", "-slave", "-quiet", "-idle", "file/to/play.avi");
// Other configuration options...
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @MadProgrammer. It worked like a charm. Wish I had stumbled upon here two days before.