# What could be wrong with my file download method?

Tags: java, javascript, download

I have an app which allows users to upload a file. User is sent to a preview page where they can download the file they just uploaded to sorta verify that things are correct. But for some reason the filename is not correct when it reaches the servlet, what could cause this?

```
$('a[id^=dl_link_]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dl_form input[name=file_name]').val($(this).text());
    $('#dl_form input[name=uid]').val(upload.tempId);
    $('#dl_form').submit();
});
```

When I add logs, I see that the file name is correct; ie "this is a test file.docx".
But when this data gets to the backend I get the following:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/yao/__TEMP__/upload_temp/1111/0gGNMY8PcAWEs3M/this�is�a�test�file.docx (No such file or directory)
```

The file path is constructed by combining parts together. The servlet receives the uid and the filename, everything else is from some other backend methods.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with url encoding? For example spaces becoming %20 etc.

Comment: try unescape the link

Comment: @Niels i tried to do url encode/decode, the spaces are still coming up as ? marks.

Comment: spaces shouldn't turn to special chars, even if you have bad escaping. The form itself will encodeURIComponent all the form values anyway, so that's not the issue. try hard-coding the filename and see if it writes ok to the path.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to call

```
encodeURIComponent()
```

on the file name.  It'll convert the space chars to %20 and then be converted properly on the back end.

Comment: i tried encoding the filename via js, then decode in back with java. the spaces are still coming up as ? marks.

Answer (score 1):

As I see the problem is related with the space character. This question might help you: [accessing files with spaces in filename from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358850/accessing-files-with-spaces-in-filename-from-java)