# Read file with whitespace in name using Java?

Tags: java, path

The original name of file is `1_00100 0042.jpg`. I have a problem:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 49: file:///opt/storage/user-data/attachments/1_00100\ 0042.jpg
```

Can you give me some solutions how to get this file using this bad path? I know that C# have Path class. Is there something similar in Java?

I tried to do next but not successfully:

```java
private String replaceWhitespace(String str) {
    if (str.contains(" ")) {
        str = str.replace(" ", "%20");
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Here you go:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487389/convert-string-to-uri

Comment: @Dawnkeeper Standard Java (not Android JDK) doesn't have `Uri` but `URI` class which unfortunately doesn't have `parse` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing files with spaces in filename from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5358850/608639), [Read file with whitespace in its path using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9128288/608639), and friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use File, it works with whitespaces:

```
String path = "file:///opt/storage/user-data/attachments/1_00100\\ 0042.jpg";
File f = new File(path);
```

If you want to replace spaces with %20 then use regex:

```
path.replaceAll("\\u0020", "%20");
```

Comment: This doesn't do what you think. For instance check result of `f.getName()` for user input `"file:///opt/storage/user-data/attachments/1_00100\\ 0042.jpg"`.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you are exposing, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Your code will not compile because ``\`` in Java is special character which needs additional ``\`` to be literal, so you need to write it as `"\\"`. About result of `getName()` strange thing happens because in Java8 it will be only `0042.jpg` while in Java7 I see `1_00100\ 0042.jpg`  (example http://ideone.com/m2FsuT). I am not sure why there is such difference.

Comment: oh you meant the escaping, that's right I missed it, sorry I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure where did you get this path but I assume that `\` before space was added to escape it so you need to change your method to also remove this `\` before space.
Also since this method doesn't affect state of instance of your class you can make it `static`.

```
private static String replaceWhitespace(String str) {
    if (str.contains("\\ ")) {
        str = str.replace("\\ ", "%20");
    }
    return str;
}
```

Demo:

```
String file = "file:///opt/storage/user-data/attachments/1_00100\\ 0042.jpg";
file = replaceWhitespace(file);

URI u = new URI(file);
System.out.println(u.getRawPath());
System.out.println(u.getPath());
```

output:

```
/opt/storage/user-data/attachments/1_00100%200042.jpg
/opt/storage/user-data/attachments/1_00100 0042.jpg
```