# Loading assets from Flutter in Java won't work if the path has spaces

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

Loading assets from Flutter in Java doesn't work if the path has spaces:

```
val assetPath2 = "sound_packs/packs/Blaze_Kit/Clap.wav"
val loader = FlutterInjector.instance().flutterLoader()
val key = loader.getLookupKeyForAsset(assetPath2)
val inputStream: InputStream = context.assets.open(key)
val assetFD: AssetFileDescriptor = context.assets.openFd(key)
```

With underscore:

`val assetPath2 = "sound_packs/packs/Blaze_Kit/Clap.wav"`

it worked

but for

`val assetPath2 = "sound_packs/packs/Blaze Kit/Clap.wav"`

it doesn't work:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewStringUTF called with pending exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: flutter_assets/sound_packs/packs/Blaze Kit/Clap.wav
12-20 16:40:26.544 12887 12887 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:523]   at long android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(java.lang.String, int) (AssetManager.java:-2)
12-20 16:40:26.544 12887 12887 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:523]   at java.io.InputStream android.content.res.AssetManager.open(java.lang.String, int) (AssetManager.java:374)
12-20 16:40:26.544 12887 12887 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:523]   at java.io.InputStream android.content.res.AssetManager.open(java.lang.String) (AssetManager.java:348)
12-20 16:40:26.544 12887 12887 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:523]   at boolean com.example.flutter_app.JNI$Companion.loadWavAsset(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, float) (JNI.kt:47)
```

This is the pubspec.yaml:

```
assets:
    - 'sound_packs/packs/Blaze Kit/'
    - 'sound_packs/packs/Blaze_Kit/'
```

I have the 2 folders named `Blaze Kit` and `Blaze_Kit` with the same file `Clap.wav` inside of it.

Is this a bug or desired behaviour? Is there a way to encode the space in the path for the assets?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read file with whitespace in name using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828105/read-file-with-whitespace-in-name-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is intended.  Reading filenames terminates on the last character, so a space in the filename (That includes folders) would terminate the file read on that space.  Best just to use an underscore or dash.