# File path with spaces

Tags: java

```
String filepath = E:\TestCode\My Demo File\abc.xml
```

I am trying to create file using this file path, this file path having spaces.

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(file);
```

It throws a `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html. You need to use "\\" instead of "\" in a string.

Comment: do you know which of those 4 lines is throwing the exception?

Comment: `String filepath = E:\TestCode\My Demo File\abc.xml` won't compile..

Comment: How do you know that the spaces are the problem ? Did you test with a filename without spaces in its path ?

Comment: `String filepath = E:\TestCode\My Demo File\abc.xml` in not a valid java statement

Comment: As above, post **all** of your source code as a minimum, etc example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing files with spaces in filename from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5358850/608639), [Read file with whitespace in its path using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9128288/608639), and friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When specifying Windows file paths, you have to escape the '\' character, otherwise the path specified will not be exactly what you expect. The correct way to specify the path would be:

```
String filepath = "E:\\TestCode\\My Demo File\\abc.xml";
```

Or, you can use a forward slash as the path separator, the `File` class will automatically convert it to the correct separator for your platform:

```
String filepath = "E:/TestCode/My Demo File/abc.xml";
```

I have added the missing quotes and semicolon that were missing from the code you provided in your original question.

Comment: Or just use `/` because `File` is smart enough to work out the correct separator...

Comment: @Laf - I have tried to update my file with forward slash. Its saying FileNotFoundException . Can you please help me to resolve it?