# ERROR: input directory 'Files' does not exist

Tags: java, android, command-line, aapt

need to build the R.java file from resource using the command line. I do this using the following Java program. I get the

> ERROR: input directory 'Files' does not exist

here is my code can anyone help which file directory is missing. or why this error is popped up.

```
public static String ProjectPath = "C:\\Users\\Muzammil-Husnain\\testing\\Soothing-snow-fall";
public static String ANDROID_HOME = "C:\\\"Program Files (x86)\"\\Android\\android-sdk";

public static void generateRfile() {
    try {
        File projectDirectoryFile = new File(ProjectPath);
        String command = "aapt package -v -f -m "+
        " -S \""+projectDirectoryFile.getCanonicalPath()+"\\res\"" +
        " -J \""+projectDirectoryFile.getCanonicalPath()+"\\gen\"" +
        " -M \""+projectDirectoryFile.getCanonicalPath()+"\\AndroidManifest.xml\"" +
        " -I C:\\\"Program Files (x86)\"\\Android\\android-sdk\\platforms\\android-21\\android.jar\"";
        System.out.println("Directory Path : "+projectDirectoryFile.getCanonicalPath());
        System.out.println(command);
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RunApplicationOnPrject.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

[image: Here is The Directory]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found Error

`" -I C:\\\"Program Files (x86)\"\\Android\\android-sdk\\platforms\\android-21\\android.jar\"";`

This Line was missing starting quote of the URL, while it contains ending quoteI fixed error
by including quote like this:

```
" -I \"C:\\\"Program Files (x86)\"\\Android\\android-sdk\\platforms\\android-21\\android.jar\""
```

Thanks to @Prashant and @Laszlo Lugosi for your attention.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use quote "" when there is SPACE in a directory name. Batch file assume Files as next parameter in Program Files.

Comment: There isn't any directory name with space. I have pasted directory snapshot. kindly review.

Comment: -I C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk\\platforms\\android-21\\android.jar - there are spaces in "Program Files (x86)"

Answer (score 3):

your error is because of

```
public static String ANDROID_HOME = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk";
```

here space is present in `Program Files (x86)`.

You can check [accessing file having space in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358850/accessing-files-with-spaces-in-filename-from-java)

Comment: I have updated my code and placed quote "" arround the Program Files (x86) but still same error is making my day bad.

Comment: you can use `URL url = file.toURI().toURL();` or `URLDecoder.decode(path);`

Answer (score 1):

I've had same error but with apktool. Message states, that "ERROR: input directory 'ini' does not exist". Nothing helps, but suddenly I've found next lines in apk_dir/apktool.yml file:

```
doNotCompress:
- js
- ''
- ini
- dat
- cfg
- xml
```

After removing those lines error gone.

UPD: removing only line with quotes `- ''` solves problem

Comment: You only have to remove the line `- ' ' `.

It was a bug, fixed in the upcoming `2.1.0` release.