# How to access file that have space character in it's name in using java?

Tags: java, linux, file, exception, filenotfoundexception

I'm not able to access files with spaces in its name.

My Code:

```
String fileName = "This is my file.txt";
String path = "/home/myUsername/folder/";
String filePath = path + filename;
f = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
```

I'm getting `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Please read through this while adding a new question 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is the file actually there?

Comment: Also, remember that linux filesystems are usually (always?) case-sensitive, so `"This is my file.txt"` is different from `"This is My File.txt"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing files with spaces in filename from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5358850/608639), [Read file with whitespace in its path using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9128288/608639), and friends.

Comment: dude, I have just written a code and checked it. I think your file path is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing there is a typo in parameter fileName:

```
String **fileName** = "This is my file.txt";
    String filePath = path + **filename**;
```

Here is the updated code with your example:

```
  String fileName = "This is my file.txt";
            String path = File.separator + "home" + File.separator + "myUsername" + File.separator + "folder" + File.separator;
            String filePath = path + fileName;
            BufferedInputStream f = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
```

> I am able to read the file with spaces in file name.
>
> Using  File.separator we let the code to replace the file separator based
>   on OS.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
public class AccessMyFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("/home/This is my file.txt");
        System.out.println(file.exists());//true
        System.out.println(file.isFile());//true
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        while(bis.available()>0) {
            System.out.print((char)bis.read());
        }
    }//main
}//class
```

> File: /home/This is my file.txt

Output:

```
hello world
```

Use **java.io.File** for checking if exists or not. Then you know your code is working or not.